# Why am I getting `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` in explain query?

Tags: mysql, explain

I have a unique compound key like fr(fromid,toid) in the table, when I run the query with explain I get the following result:

```
Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`
```

The query I ran:

```
explain SELECT rid FROM relationship WHERE fromid=78 AND toid=60
```

Any help?

**EDIT1:**
When I use the below query:

```
explain SELECT rid FROM relationship WHERE fromid=60 and toid=78 AND is_approved='s'  OR is_approved='f' OR is_approved='t'
```

I see `USING WHERE` instead of the previous message, but when I use the below query:

```
explain SELECT rid FROM relationship WHERE fromid=60 and toid=78 AND (is_approved='s'  OR is_approved='f' OR is_approved='t')
```

I again get the first `impossible ...` message! What these parenthesis do here?

**EDIT2:**

```
CREATE TABLE `relationship` (
 `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fromid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `toid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `is_approved` char(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `fromid` (`fromid`,`toid`),
 KEY `toid` (`toid`),
 CONSTRAINT `relationship_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fromid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `relationship_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`toid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**EDIT3:**
[As mysql site say:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html)

> Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
>
> MySQL has read all const (and system) tables and notice that the WHERE
>   clause is always false.

But in the query I get the result I want, the `WHERE` part is not `false`. Is there someone who could explain this and shed some light on the subject?

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM relationship WHERE fromid=78 AND toid=60;` return ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, there will be `using index` in extra instead of `impossible...`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are getting the message

> Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

This is documented in [the page you already linked](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html).

> MySQL has read all `const` (and `system`) tables and notice that the `WHERE` clause is always false

`const` tables are defined as

> The table has at most one matching row, which is read at the start of
>   the query.  ... `const` is used when you compare all parts of a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`
>   index to constant values.

You have a `UNIQUE KEY` on  `(fromid,toid)`. The query on `WHERE fromid=78 AND toid=60` can be satisfied by reading this unique index. From the message you are getting this must return no results.

Similarly the query `WHERE fromid=60 and toid=78 AND (is_approved='s'  OR is_approved='f' OR is_approved='t')` can also use this index to locate the row of interest (though it still has a residual predicate to evaluate were any row to match).

Your other query is different

```
SELECT rid
FROM   relationship
WHERE  fromid = 60
       AND toid = 78
       AND is_approved = 's'
        OR is_approved = 'f'
        OR is_approved = 't'
```

`AND` has a higher precedence than `Or`, so this is the same as

```
SELECT rid
FROM   relationship
WHERE  ( ( fromid = 60 ) AND ( toid = 78 ) AND ( is_approved = 's' ) )
        OR ( is_approved = 'f' )
        OR ( is_approved = 't' )
```

This can no longer use that index and has different semantics in that it will return *any* rows where `is_approved IN ('f','t')` irrespective of what the values in the other columns are.

Comment: So how should I say for example: if its `fromid=12 AND toid=78` then check if `is_approved='f'` or `is_approved='t'` or `is_approved='s'`

Comment: @john.locke: That is your third query: `WHERE fromid=60 AND toid=78 AND (is_approved='s' OR is_approved='f' OR is_approved='t')` which can also be written as: `WHERE fromid=60 AND toid=78 AND ( is_approved IN ('s', 'f', 't') )`

Comment: @ypercube, The above query will result in 'impossible...' bacause of `is_approved IN()`

Comment: Exactly. Because no row matches the `fromid=60 AND toid=78` part so no further check is needed (for the `is_approved` part).

Comment: I have rows that matches `fromid=60 AND toid=78`

Comment: You can't have row **s** that do. There is a unique constraint on `(fromid,toid)` so there would be a maximum of one surely? And from the message you say you are getting MySQL doesn't think that there is even one that does. Do you mean that you have some rows that match `fromid=60` and some rows that match `toid=78` but not necessarily the same rows?

Comment: Perhaps this is the *`AND-OR` confusion*. Maybe you want all rows that have `fromid=60` and all rows that have `toid=78` and then from those, keep only those that have either `'s'` or `'f'` or `t'` is_approved? If yes, try this condition: `WHERE (fromid=60 OR toid=78) AND (is_approved IN ('s', 'f', 't'))`

Answer (score 5):

MySql Explain uses the values you provide, literally, to traverse rows of the associated tables.  If you provide a constant/key value which is not in the associated table, MySql Explain will stop with this error.  Simply query the associated table(s) for values which do exist and provide those in your Explain query and everything will work as expected.

Comment: `Impossible WHERE noticed ...` is not an error. It's part of the explain.

Answer (score 3):

`Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` in explain query?

This error occurs due to invalid value being put on a column which are either primary key or unique key.

Try with a correct value in the `where` clause .

Answer (score 0):

I'm jumping into this late.  But here is what I noticed for me.

I was doing this query and the item column was UNIQUE.

```
SELECT `vari-groupid` FROM shop_item_variations_group where `item` = 'itemnu1' limit 1
```

which would get the **Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables**

All I had to do was change "=" to "like" and it now is using my index.

```
SELECT `vari-groupid` FROM shop_item_variations_group where `item` like 'itemnu1' limit 1
```

Comment: Was it not using the index with the `=` ?

Comment: No crazy enough it wasn't....  It was just saying this in the explain Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

Comment: Yes, but that "impossible WHERE" is usually good. means the query doesn't have to read any more from the tables or indexes. Was it slow? If not, you should not worry at all.